# JFreeChart array as dataset

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart to plot a line graph. I would like to load arrays as the data set... one array for the x-axis and another array for the y-axis. 
I am having a problem when trying to pass the array as the data to use in the dataset.
The following is what I've tried;

```
public DefaultCategoryDataset createDataset(int[] epochNo, int[] BFacts)
{

    final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    for (int i = 0; i<epochNo.length(); i++)
    {
        dataset.addValue(epochNo[i], BFacts[i]);
    }
    return dataset;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem you're referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions; with a normal line chart, you use a `DefaultCategoryDataset`. The `addValue` method has **three** arguments, the second being the name of the dataset. And the third is the column label:

```
dataset.addValue(BFacts[i], "myline", String.valueOf(epochNo[i]));
```

There other solution is to see this as an XY line chart (using `ChartFactory.createXYLineChart`). In that case your dataset is an `XYDataset` instead of a `CategoryDataset`:

```
private XYDataset createDataset(int[] epochNo, int[] bFacts) {
    final XYSeries myline = new XYSeries( "myline" );          
    for (int i = 0; i < epochNo.length; i++) {
        myline.add(epochNo[i], bFacts[i]);
    }      
    final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection( );          
    dataset.addSeries(myline);          
    return dataset;
}
```

[See more in this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jfreechart/jfreechart_xy_chart.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just cannot understand how the structure of the project could be ... at the moment this is what I have ;

Comment: public class MyClass extends JFrame
    {
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

    //train the neural network and fill chartEpoch & chartBFacts 
    //When trained do the chart i.e. Chart(chartEpoch, chartBFacts);

    }
    }

    //method to create chart
    //method to create Dataset